# Android: Camera2 Bad argument passed to camera service

Tags: android, image, android-camera, camera2

Can somebody what I have done wrong... I wanted to capture the image which I have a preview screen using SurfaceView. I am able to show the preview on the surface view.

This is my code to capture the image

```
if (mCameraSession == null && mCameraDevice == null) return;

    ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(mTexturePreviewSize.getWidth(),
                            mTexturePreviewSize.getHeight(),
                            ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
    reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(imageAvailableListener, mBackgroundHandler);

    Surface surface = reader.getSurface();
    try {

        CaptureRequest.Builder requestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
        requestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
        mCameraSession.capture(requestBuilder.build(), sessionCaptureListener, null);
```

Below is the error message i received.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad argument passed to camera service
        at android.hardware.camera2.utils.CameraBinderDecorator.throwOnError(CameraBinderDecorator.java:114)
        at android.hardware.camera2.utils.CameraBinderDecorator$CameraBinderDecoratorListener.onAfterInvocation(CameraBinderDecorator.java:73)
        at android.hardware.camera2.utils.Decorator.invoke(Decorator.java:81)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:397)
        at $Proxy2.submitRequestList(Unknown Source)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.submitCaptureRequest(CameraDeviceImpl.java:617)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.capture(CameraDeviceImpl.java:503)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.capture(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:161)
        at Control.CameraApi21Plus.captureSinglePhoto(CameraApi21Plus.java:171)
        at com.CameraActivity$2.onClick(CameraActivity.java:108)
```

Capturing a single photo function:

```
   public void captureSinglePhoto() {

    if (mCameraSession == null && mCameraDevice == null) return;

    ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(mTexturePreviewSize.getWidth(),
            mTexturePreviewSize.getHeight(),
            ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
    reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(imageAvailableListener, mBackgroundHandler);

    Surface surface = reader.getSurface();
    try {

        CaptureRequest.Builder requestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
        requestBuilder.addTarget(surface);

        mCameraSession.stopRepeating();
        mCameraSession.capture(requestBuilder.build(), sessionCaptureListener, null);

    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener imageAvailableListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
        Image img = reader.acquireLatestImage();
    }
};

private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback sessionCaptureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
        //super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only capture to a surface that is configured for the session, so you should prepare the surface before the session is created.

In the official document:

> **IllegalArgumentException**  if the request targets no Surfaces or
>   Surfaces that are **not configured as outputs for this session**; ...

Just like there, you need to have the surface `mImageReader.getSurface()` ready when you create the session

```
           mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, mImageReader.getSurface()),
                new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                    ...
                }, null);
```

official sample:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/tree/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic

Comment: I want to give a tick to Diyoda but your one is more direct. I looked at the sample , is too many thing in there AF, AE i have no idea how it work in camera. I don't know much about camera.

Comment: Yes, Camera flow is actually quite complex. If you only want to get a photo, you should use Camera Intent, http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html, good luck

Comment: And, TBH, if you understand the details you would know that Diyoda's claim on `you are calling a closed session` is actually not the case, i.e. you can see your preview.

Comment: You are right..Derek.. I know I haven't closed the session but didn't realize i  have to add extra surface to the list. Now I have get rid of that force close. I think now I have to set camera to setRepeatRequest to give a preview running again.

Answer (score 2):

In Camera2 API,

Quoting from the documentation of `CameraCaptureSession`,

> If a new session is created by the camera device, then the previous
>   session     is closed, and its associated onClosed callback will 
>   be invoked. All of the session methods will throw an
>   IllegalStateException if called once the session is closed.

So, as the documentation implies, you are calling a closed session. find this out. I can help a bit more of you put more code.

And also, I hope that you are imitating the Camera2 API sample code.If not I suggest you to have a look at [it](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic).